# php curl trying to retrieve page but not working

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to retrieve a form from [this page](http://services.www.gov.qa/TV/continue/TV/TV_TrafficViolation/2/CPN). I set up the cookie and also sent form data, but all i get back is invalid page.

```
$ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");


$ch = curl_init ("http://services.www.gov.qa/TV/process/TV/TV_TrafficViolation?lang=en&notloggedin=true");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec ($ch);


$ch = curl_init ("http://services.www.gov.qa/TV/continue/TV/TV_TrafficViolation/2/CPN");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$data = array(
    'sopEngineTabRef' => '1376927282615',
    'act' => 'byCarPlateNo',
    'txiVehicleNumber' => '',
    'mnuVehicleType' => 'PRV',
    'vehicleNumberNType' => '12332/PRV',
    'searchCriteria' => '1',
    'searchCriteria' => 'qatariUser1',
    'vehicleNumberAndType' => '12332/PRV',
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
echo $output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: The "this page" link seems to go to a transaction unsuccessful page.  Also, I tried just wrapping your code in php tags and opening it and it definitely is returning something from there, it's just an error page sent by the web-server.  It does contain a lot of relative links to other pages and code on their server that aren't being resolved locally, however.

Comment: you have to start from this page:http://services.www.gov.qa/TV/process/TV/TV_TrafficViolation?lang=en&notloggedin=true and then click on search by plate number.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like one problem is the page you are returning contains a ton of jQuery/js/ajax content that you are going to have to parse out and interpret -- curl is basically just going to display html.  Also it's returning items like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/TV/hukoomi/scripts/hukoomi_combined_js.js"></script>
```

Which your script is going to try to find in your current local directory, that would need to be rewritten with the full path, ie http://services.www.gov.qa/TV/hukoomi/scripts/hukoomi_combined_js.js

Comment: I re-wrote to remove 404s. Still getting the same result.It seem as if the form data is not going to that page.

Comment: It looked like the session cookies are being created in the file right.  But for one thing when I go in a clean browser to the first page then try to click through to another link I get an expired session page.  I wonder if you need to start at another page to get a valid session?

Comment: Yes that's right. I just realized you have to open this page first: http://portal.www.gov.qa/wps/portal/services/settlementoftrafficviolation

The page i linked before is inside an iframe of this. How to i modify my code to get cookies from both the main page and iframe?